# How to access SharePoint list from R?

Tags: r, sharepoint, odata

I have been trying to connect sharepoint list from RStudio.

Can you please help me in this?

It seems R-Odata *package* is limited to csv files.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792265/using-r-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-list

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to any SharePoint resources now, and I haven't for quite some time, but I would surmise that you ingest the HTML just as you would with any HTML-based technology.

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("http://www.bls.gov/web/empsit/cesbmart.htm")

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

head(tbls)
## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <table id="main-content-table">&#13;\n\t<tr>&#13;\n\t\t<td id="secon ...
## [2] <table id="Table1" class="regular" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" x ...
## [3] <table id="Table2" class="regular" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" x ...
## [4] <table id="Table3" class="regular" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" x ...
## [5] <table id="Table4" class="regular" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" x ...
## [6] <table id="Exhibit1" class="regular" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ...
```

Then...

```
tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
        html_nodes("table") %>%
        .[3:4] %>%
        html_table(fill = TRUE)

str(tbls_ls)
```

Also...

```
# empty list to add table data to
tbls2_ls <- list()

# scrape Table 2. Nonfarm employment...
tbls2_ls$Table1 <- webpage %>%
        html_nodes("#Table2") %>% 
        html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
        .[[1]]

# Table 3. Net birth/death...
tbls2_ls$Table2 <- webpage %>%
        html_nodes("#Table3") %>% 
        html_table() %>%
        .[[1]]

str(tbls2_ls)
```

Finally...

```
head(tbls2_ls[[1]], 4)
##   CES Industry Code CES Industry Title Benchmark Estimate Differences   NA
## 1            Amount            Percent      <NA>     <NA>          NA <NA>
## 2         00-000000      Total nonfarm   137,214  137,147          67  (1)
## 3         05-000000      Total private   114,989  114,884         105  0.1
## 4         06-000000    Goods-producing    18,675   18,558         117  0.6

# remove row 1 that includes part of the headings
tbls2_ls[[1]] <- tbls2_ls[[1]][-1,]

# rename table headings
colnames(tbls2_ls[[1]]) <- c("CES_Code", "Ind_Title", "Benchmark",
                            "Estimate", "Amt_Diff", "Pct_Diff")

head(tbls2_ls[[1]], 4)
##    CES_Code         Ind_Title Benchmark Estimate Amt_Diff Pct_Diff
## 2 00-000000     Total nonfarm   137,214  137,147       67      (1)
## 3 05-000000     Total private   114,989  114,884      105      0.1
## 4 06-000000   Goods-producing    18,675   18,558      117      0.6
## 5 07-000000 Service-providing   118,539  118,589      -50      (1)

library(XML)

url <- "http://www.bls.gov/web/empsit/cesbmart.htm"

# read in HTML data
tbls_xml <- readHTMLTable(url)

typeof(tbls_xml)
## [1] "list"

length(tbls_xml)
## [1] 15
```

See the links below for more details.

http://bradleyboehmke.github.io/2015/12/scraping-html-tables.html

https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/r-reading-webpages

http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/webscrape.html

Comment: Hi, Its throwing me error while I try to do read_html("site") : Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 401.